# Melt able to remove NA's for some variables but not others?

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a question regarding the melt function from the reshape2 package in R.

I would like to melt a multi-dimensional array, keeping NA's for some of the variables, but removing NA's for the rest. An example to illustrate what I don't want:

```
library(reshape2)
subtotals <- tapply(
  mtcars$mpg,
  list(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp,mtcars$drat,mtcars$wt), 
  sum
)
subtotals_melted <- melt(subtotals, na.rm = T) # removes NA's for all vars
```

I know that there is a `na.rm=` option in the `melt` function, but it removes the `NA`'s for all variables. As such subtotal-ing operations typically take up quite a bit of memory due to implicit `NA`'s, after being melted, I was wondering if there was a faster and more memory-efficient way to implement such a use-case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need a strategy.  I would probably create separate dataframes for the two sets of variables, melt them separately as you wish, then merge or cbind together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

result =
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt) %>%
  summarize(sum_mpg = sum(mpg, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

This will preserve NA levels in the grouping variables but not mpg. In general, though, I agree with Michael Bellhouse that conditional mutation is usually best done by separating into two separate dataframes.

Comment: what does the '%>%' operator do? also does it have a proper name? I got an error saying 'Error: could not find function "%>%"'

Comment: Oh yeah, the %>% operator is in the magrittr package. It does chaining/piping. dplyr is also required.